# No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I searched previous solutions and couldn't solve it. I am getting this error after trying to run the jar file of my spring boot application:
**"No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct."**

My pom.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>mygym</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyGym</name>
    <description>Gym management web service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

The error is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\MyGym\out\artifacts\MyGym_jar\MyGym.jar
23:30:31.016 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Activating profiles []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                        

23:30:31.143 [main] INFO com.example.MyGym.MyGymApplication - Starting MyGymApplication on DESKTOP-ORO4NEA with PID 13572 (C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\MyGym\out\artifacts\MyGym_jar\MyGym.jar started by user in C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\MyGym)
23:30:31.143 [main] DEBUG com.example.MyGym.MyGymApplication - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
23:30:31.143 [main] INFO com.example.MyGym.MyGymApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
23:30:31.144 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.example.MyGym.MyGymApplication
23:30:31.199 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@86be70a
23:30:31.209 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
23:30:31.268 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/MyGym/out/artifacts/MyGym_jar/MyGym.jar!/com/example/MyGym/DBCreator.class]
23:30:31.271 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/MyGym/out/artifacts/MyGym_jar/MyGym.jar!/com/example/MyGym/EmailService.class]
23:30:31.285 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/MyGym/out/artifacts/MyGym_jar/MyGym.jar!/com/example/MyGym/GymController.class]
23:30:31.287 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/MyGym/out/artifacts/MyGym_jar/MyGym.jar!/com/example/MyGym/GymRepository.class]
23:30:31.312 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:467)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:434)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.example.MyGym.MyGymApplication.main(MyGymApplication.java:10)
23:30:31.315 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@86be70a, started on Sun Aug 30 23:30:31 IDT 2020

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would really appreciate some help solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure all dependencies downloaded successfully, then package your spring boot application from terminal command line:

```
mvn install

mvn clean package
```